# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in React ajax Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, flux

I am new to react js.I am little confused with loading initial data in reactjs.
I am pretty sure that my ajax call is working But I don't Know How to handle that data and manipulate that json data to my component.
App.js

```
var React = require('react');
var Actions = require('../actions');
var Store = require('../stores/store');
var Nav =require('./Nav');
var Fakeprofile = require('./Fakeprofile');
var Sidemenu = require('./Sidemenu');
var Bulkmail = require('./Bulkmail');
var store = require('../stores/store');
var api = require('../utils');
function getAppState() {

    return {

    }
}


var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState:function () {
       return getAppState();
   },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        api.getprofile().then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                data:response

            });
        });

        Store.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    componentUnmount: function(){
        Store.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },



    render:function () {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return(
            <div>
                <Nav/>
                <Sidemenu/>
                <Fakeprofile data={this.state.data} />



            </div>

        )
    },
    _onChange: function(){
        this.setState(getAppState());
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Utils.js

```
var actions = require('./actions');

module.exports = {
  getprofile:function () {
      console.log('Gettinf data');
      var url  = 'http://localhost:3000/api/index';
      $.ajax({
          url:url,
          dataType:'json',
          cache:false,
          success:function success(data) {
              console.log(data);



          }.bind(this),
          error:function error(xhr,status,err) {
              console.log(err);
          }
      })
  }
};
```

Comment: Where is jQuery defined?

Comment: jquery defined in index.html file And Ajax is working But i don't know how to handle that data

Comment: `$.ajax()` is not returned from `getprofile()` call?

Comment: @charlietfl yes sir that was my mistake

Comment: $.ajax() is returning the json data.

Comment: _"$.ajax() is returning the json data."_ Yes, though `$.ajax()` is not returned from `getprofile()` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jQuery is defined try including [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement before `$.ajax()` to return jQuery promise object from `getprofile()` call

```
getprofile:function () {
      console.log('Gettinf data');
      var url  = 'http://localhost:3000/api/index';
      // add `return` before `$.ajax()` to return jQuery promise
      // from `getprofile()` call
      return $.ajax({
          url:url,
          dataType:'json',
          cache:false,
          success:function success(data) {
              console.log(data);



          }.bind(this),
          error:function error(xhr,status,err) {
              console.log(err);
          }
      })
  }
```

Comment: Yup BIngo!! Data is getting But now This Happened `TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

Comment: Instead of using `.bind()` at `success`, try using `$.ajaxSetup()` to set `context` of `$.ajax()` call to the object where `setState` is a method. `$.ajaxSetup({context:/* object to set as this for $.ajax() */})`, also, try using `.then()` to handle response instead of `success` `return $.ajax({
          url:url,
          dataType:'json',
          cache:false})`

Comment: Have you tried setting `this` to `App` at `$.ajax()` call within `module.exports = {
  getprofile:function () {}`?

Comment: Actually i forgot to bind the data in componentdidmount

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd to me using AJAX in react when there is React native Fetch methods to do this.

This is how I would do it.

```
getProfile: function() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/index',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       });
```

Then in your App.js

This is where your error was - you need to return a response in the .then.

```
componentDidMount: function(){
        api.getprofile().then(response => response.json())
        .then( (json => {
            this.setState({
            data: json
        });
    });
}
```